# Share unchanging data from a central repository on a network

Tags: linux, file-sharing, storage

I have a bunch of different binary files (total size of all files is circa ~500GB) stored in a hard drive that is mounted to `machine001`.

I have 200 other machines that need to access this data for **read-only** purposes.

What is the best way to share this data with all other computers, so that reads are fastest? (I use Ubuntu Linux)

Is there a different scheme that would be even better for fastest reads?

Comment: What sort of data is it? You say it gets updated often, what updates it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, NFS uses UDP, and maybe you'ill need some extra coding to ensure that no files get lost. I don't like it and it's not fully supported on all OSes.

Maybe FTP is your answer for FAST reading, so FAST transferences since no software is faster than FTP to do so.

But you say that you have a total size of ~500GB. You can implement some VCS using checksums to know what files need to be updated, but it's more coding and there are lots of VCS's. However, I think FTP is the best way if you want portability, and maybe read access does not imply a copy of everything. Even this way, FTP is the fastest one.

So, if you want a VCS, to **transfer** just needed files, just fast. If you have Unix-like systems on all computers, you can install [GIT](http://git-scm.com/), and use `git pull` to update the repos. Nobody will be able to write to your repo, and just needed files will be updated, fast.

Comment: thank you D4RIO. what do I need to do in order to setup FTP? do I need a server? do I need lots of RAM?

Comment: You need a server, see http://www.proftpd.org/

Comment: FTP fastest? On what benchmarks? For random-access data? I've downvoted this answer because I think this is not correct and imposes an extra level of inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

NFS is the obvious answer.

If the clients have space for caches, and the data updates infrequently, you could do various things such as storing the data in a version control system or mirroring it with rsync.

Comment: Isn't AFS supposed to be better than NFS?

Comment: the data does update frequently. is NFS the fastest way to go? is there a better way?

Will storing the data in a central DB lead to faster reads? or would it be better to try and 'cache' as much as possible on every machine, and each machine will use its 'own' version of the data?

Comment: Possibly AFS is better, but NFS is simpler, older and more widely used. I don't have any benchmarks.<br> Database: this depends what your data is and how it's indexed, and what your access patterns are.

Answer (score 0):

The ultimate way to make reads fasts would be to copy all the data to all the clients once and for all, but I guess you don't want to spend the space.

Are people likely to access the same file more than once from a given client? If so, I'd go for a simple approach with aggressive caching. Something like a WebDAV or FTP server, [Fusedav](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/fusedav/) or [CurlFTPfs](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/) on the clients, and a caching HTTP proxy on each client ([Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) or [wwwoffle](http://www.gedanken.demon.co.uk/wwwoffle/)).